# Landscape and Portrait view in android tablet

Tags: android

I am working on android. I will tried the following code to prevent the application to restart when the tab or phone is rotated. It is working but it does not give the landscape and portrait view correctly.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually,

```
          android:configChanges="orientation"
          android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

attributes of an `Activity` declaration in the Manifest doesn't prevent the *activity* from being recreated whenever orientation changes, it prevents the platform from doing anything to the orientation by default and keeps it by default e.g. landscape.

You can override

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.newLayout);
}
```

to force recreation of the activity.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 layouts (portrait and landscape) and the order seems to be reversed on the tablet then switch to using `getRotation` instead of deprecated `getOrientation`. Something like this

```
private void setLayout() {
    // Get display for detecting the phone orientation
    final Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0 || display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.home_l);
    }
}
```